# boost::serialization - into string

Tags: serialization, boost

Is it possible to serialize data structures (using boost::serialization) into string variable or buffer (not into file on disk)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, make it do its work on a `stringstream`.

Comment: And the same goes for other streams.